# Android Google Sign In fails with error code 8

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am attempting to integrate Google Sign in to my application, but I get an Error with Status Code 8.  I am debugging from Xamarin using the Xamarin Andriod Emulator.

I have added my debug.keystore SHA1 to my Google Credentials and have correctly set the package name to match what I have in my manifest.  My app is running in Debug mode.

I am using Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth version 29.0.0.2 which is the latest stable versio,

My code is pretty much a copy paste from the Andriod docs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

  SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);

  var googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions
    .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
    .RequestEmail()
    .Build();

  _googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
      .AddConnectionCallbacks(ConnectionCallback, ConnectionSuspendedCallback)
      .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(ConnectionFailed)
    .AddApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions)
    .Build();

  var signInButtonGooglePlus = FindViewById<SignInButton>(Resource.Id.signInButtonGooglePlus);

  signInButtonGooglePlus.SetSize(SignInButton.SizeWide);
  signInButtonGooglePlus.SetScopes(googleSignInOptions.GetScopeArray());

  signInButtonGooglePlus.Click += SignInButtonGooglePlus_Click;
}

void SignInButtonGooglePlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(_googleApiClient);
    StartActivityForResult(signInIntent, RESULT_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == RESULT_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
    {
        var signInResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        HandleSignInResult(signInResult);
    }
}
```